# Time picker missing in Kibana Discover

Tags: elasticsearch

Just learning elastic search and Kibana.  It seems on my index the time picker is missing.
[image: missing date field]

However I do have a date field in my index

This is ES7.  I see references to @timestamp on google for previous versions but Im not sure what I should be doing in ES7

**Updated Nov. 14**
Below is a portion of my document. The save_date is what I want the time index to use.  The document has over 800 fields so I didnt put in the whole thing.
[image: datasample with save_date field]

This is also a portion of the mapping that Im interested in
[image: mapping]

Comment: Can you share an example of a document in your index? Just copy and paste the value of the `json` tab in discover. When you create an index pattern in Kibana you need to choose the time field that will be used, if you do not choose one, you won't have the time picker.

Comment: Yeah I figured that there had to be a way to tell ES/Kibana what timestamp to use.  but Im not clear how.

Comment: The document you shared does not have that `star_time` you said, you have two field that have a date `@save_date` and `@save_time`, but those fields are not being recognized as a date field by elasticsearch. How are you ingesting the documents? You will need to correctly parse those fields so they can be recognized as a date field and you can use them when re-creating the index template.

Comment: Sorry for mistyping.  I fixed the star_time to save_date.  I've also changed date to a epoch milliseconds fields .  I've included my mapping as well to show I mapped to date.    I am using a python script.  This is a POC that I am trying to convince company we should do this.

Comment: Looking at the edits you made I would suggest that you re-create your index pattern and select the field `v300_advinfo.@save_date` as the time field, as it is mapped as a date field.

Comment: RIght.  I agree.  How do I select the field to be the time field.   Is it in the mapping?

Comment: no, you should create index pattern again and choose the related field as time

Comment: OK. I am missing something basic here.  I dont know how to 'choose the related field as time' Do I create a '. Can you create a mapping or json document with a time field.  Is the field named 'time'?
I will list how I interet this
In my mappings json I added a 'time':{'type':'date','format':'epoch_millis'} then in the document I generate I have a field named 'time' with the epoch time integer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was missing something basic.  You set the timestamp when you create the index pattern

I had created the index pattern in kibana and as time went on I kept rebuild the indexes trying different fields.  I totally missed the timestamp dropdown.